# Station to Station

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-crosswords

*The gang can't wait for their upcoming trip. Whereabouts are they headed?*

[image: grid]

```
Allow getting around ultimately insecure modern cipher
Animated show's crazy character dropping act
Asian confection made from mixing nut with jam requiring no time
Beast just released, reportedly
Board game room unoccupied, empty
Book lacking introduction about rock subgenre
Bundle of fibres tied up around top of roof
Commercial handheld console does some arithmetic
Corral confining grand university's black and white creature
Dull theoretical physicist shown up, speed of light overlooked
eSports game changing nothing for upper rank? Figures
Exploit Aussies regularly
Father transfixed by alternative moon goddess
Frolicking Sir Hugo is mischievous
Gold and money being inadequate leads to threats for some sharks
Greek wife's phaeton drawer finally lost thrice
Herb unwell after beginning to diet
Hustler's game cut short, Wright losing nothing after initially doubling up both times?
Letters read out for convenience
Lunatic aims at a bald superhero
Metal storage container's beginning to cool? 
Monopolise hotel near Go in return
No hesitation in love for essentially chaotic place
No way to delay everyone
Note case of free returns within minimalist retailer
Old place to shop for Lego renovated
One American marketing department promoted green vehicle
One is no longer coming first
Partially believe falsehood
Patronus primarily cast from lead Gryffindor!
Perhaps Dolly looks the same either way
Person getting with lover
Physical aggression cut in half by one page of fiction?
Rescue one later
Rule breaker's second to go after leader of delinquents
Secretary hiding letter from Greece
Sent back resistance unit in possession of firearm
Slog puzzles lower one's drive at first
Small, primarily decorative pot
Some online education is essential
Spiked design on paper's back-to-front
Traditional drama coming back in Honshu
Trick layer protecting egg
Type of scan for common pet
Ultimate nurse beginning to trip out
```

Entries are to be entered into the grid as-is with one letter per square, but individual clue enumerations have been withheld. Two clues produce multi-word answers, one of which is split across two grid slots.

Comment: Are we allowed to post partial solutions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Solving the Clues

*Thanks to Ankoganit, Apep, ffao, Sid, and thecoder16 for helping with the solution to this part.*

> The solutions to the clues are:
>
> ```
>  LE(E)T
>  ARCHER(character-act)*
>  MANJU*[-t]
>  GNU ~new
>  HALL + E_Y
>  EMO[-t]<
>  NE(R)VE<
>  AD+DS
>  PEN(G+U)IN
>  [-c]ARID<
>  D[o->A]TA
>  _U_S_E_
>  P(OMON*)A
>  ROGUISH*
>  OR + CAS[-h]
>  PHAE(-ton) DRA(-wer)
>  D_ + ILL
>  D_ U_ MONT(-e) D_ U_ [-o]RVILLE
>  EASE ("Es"  hom.)
>  SAITAMA*
>  [h->C]OPPER
>  H+OG<
>  Z[-er]O + _O_
>  [-st]ALL
>  DO + M(E_F<)UJI
>  FROOGLE*
>  PR+I+US
>  WAS+A
>  _LIE_
>  [-p]OTTER
>  EWE
>  MA(W+SO)N
>  VIOL[ence]+A
>  S(-a)VE(A)
>  D+E(-x)CEPTION
>  _ETA_
>  (M(IZU)HO)<
>  P+L+O+D
>  WEE+D_
>  _NEED_
>  LACED<
>  NOH<
>  PL(O)Y
>  CAT (ddef)
>  (-t)END.
> ```

#### Filling the Grid

> Some of the clues, you may notice, had no definition. These answers -- `DECEPTION`, `DOME FUJI`, `DUMONT D'URVILLE`, `HALLEY`, `MAWSON`, `MIZUHO`, `SVEA`, and `WASA` -- are all Antarctic research stations.
>
>  Here they are highlighted in the grid:
>  [image]

#### Finding the Answer

> Each station in the grid intersects at least one other station. We can plot the stations on a map of Antarctica and draw lines between the intersections:
>  [image]
>  These arrows point to **SYOWA STATION**, which is the destination from the flavortext.

Comment: maybe link to the sheet for more orderly solutions?